# Looking for knowlage about ZipInputStream

Tags: java

So when using the ZipInputStream, to get the InputStream of a Zip file on the WEB, does it download the whole ZIP file into the users computer when used?

Like for instance if the program uses the ZipInputStream to look the content of the zip, how does it really work? Does it download the zip and then look into it or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZIP file structure looks like `(LOC+Content)+ CEN`, where LOC+Content is the header and the content of each individual entry and CEN is the index.

`ZipInputStream` reads the input source sequentially one entry at a time using only the "local file (LOC)" records that precede each entry.

It does not support backtracking to previous entries meaning that it is not possible to get the list of all entries and then read the content of some entry.

It does not support the central directory (CEN) record usually located at the end of the ZIP file. Using only LOC records and ignoring CEN is technically not the correct way to read the ZIP file, but usually it is not very critical. For example, the CEN provides a way to mark some entries as deleted without physically removing them from the file, so ignoring CEN will result in reading obsolete entries.

If you need to get the list of entries in the ZIP file you will have to scan the whole file, which means downloading the whole file if it is accessed via HTTP.
If you need to read the content of some entry AFTER that you will have to open a new HTTP connection and re-read (skip) at least the amount of data until the required entry.

It seems that downloading the whole ZIP file first to the local computer and then working with a local file can be a better solution.

Comment: But you mention that if I scan the whole ZIP, it will still download it to view it. But where is the file downloaded? Or does it download each entry in the ZIP, look at it and then delete it and go for the next one?

Comment: @Veske: it all happens in memory. Downloading a file doesn't mean the file is stored anywhere on your disk. Just like your browser doesn't need to save a Youtube video on disk to play it.